# What is the food in London like or What is the food like in London?

Tags: word-order

I would like to ask if one of the two questions is correct and if both then what is the difference?

I can't honestly decide, I prefer the first one but neither the second one feels that wrong to me.

Thank you very much.

Questions:

> - What is the food in London like?
> - What is the food like in London?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is correct. I would be more likely to say "What's the food like in London?", as I have a Canadian accent and the first sounds more British to my ear.

Answer (score 0):

Neither one sounds wrong to me. Sometimes, a short prepositional phrase can be moved around in a sentence, and the sentence will still read just fine. It's more of a stylistic choice than a grammatical one; any of these would be acceptable:

> In London, what are the busses like?
>   What are the busses like in London?
>   What are the busses in London like?

When writing, we generally choose the location that helps the sentence retain its clarity and read most smoothly. When speaking, the phrase will land where it lands and, quite frankly, I don't think most native speakers give it much thought.